# What is ground on a circuit that uses AC?

Tags: ac, ground

Below is a circuit diagram for a circuit that runs off AC voltage. Where do I connect all of the points that connect to ground? Do I just connect them all on the same rail of a piece of Vero board? And does the order I connect them in matter?

[image: Circuit Diagram]
<sub>(source: [electroniq.net](http://www.electroniq.net/files/other/lm8560-digita-clock-negative.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be connected to the transformer centre tap as indicated on the schematic, otherwise the circuit won't be properly powered.

You can connect them all to the same Veroboard rail.

It's a low frequency circuit and the length and order of the connections (within reason) are immaterial.